# Getting console output from a Docker container

Tags: amazon-ec2, docker, amazon-ecs

I build an image with Python installed and a Python application too. My Python application is a *Hello, World!* application, just printing "Hello, World!" on the screen. Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:2-onbuild
CMD ["python", "./helloworld.py"]
```

In the console I execute:

```
docker run xxx/zzz
```

I can see the *Hello, World!* output. Now I am trying to execute the same application, using the task from ECS. I already pulled it to Docker Hub.

How can I see the output *Hello, World!*? Is there a way to see that my container runs correctly?

Answer (score 66, accepted):

`docker logs <container id>` will show you all the output of the container run. If you're running it on ECS, you'll probably need to set `DOCKER_HOST=tcp://ip:port` for the host that ran the container.

Comment: My container is already stopped. Using the cmd line doing, docker run -d image, it returns me the container id. Then i can make docker logs id. But running using the ECS, i cant get this log. I really cant get the container id.

Comment: it doesn't matter if the container is stopped or running, "docker logs <container id>" will get you the output. in ECS you have to log in to each instance and do a "sudo docker ps -a" to find what you are looking for.

Comment: @grayaii, I can not get logs from the stopped container via this command. Looking for an option, but haven't found yet. It is 2023, share it for the further readers.

Answer (score 33):

To view the logs of a Docker container in real time, use the following command:

```
docker logs -f <CONTAINER>
```

The `-f` or `--follow` option will show live log output. Also if the container is stopped it will fetch its logs.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe beside of tracing logs is better idea to enter into container with:

```
docker exec -it CONTAINER_ID /bin/sh
```

and investigate your process from inside.

Answer (score 0):

You can log in onto your container instance and do, for example, a `docker ps` there.

This guide describes how to connect to your container instance:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/troubleshooting.html#instance-connect

Comment: The container is not running. It already stopped so I can't connect to the container. I just want to get the messages that were printed in the console. I don't know if it is possible.

Answer (score 0):

You cam use basic output redirection to a file.

Whatever command you have running in your Dockerfile at the end of the command put >> /root/file.txt

So...
RUN ifconfig >> /root/file.txt
RUN curl google.com >> /root/file.txt

Then all you meed to do is log in to the container and type "cat /root/file.txt" to see exactly what was on screen.  Is it possible to copy from container to host at end of the Dockerfile? idk but Maybe.