# How to get the output of a docker image

Tags: docker, docker-compose

when i do

```
docker run consoleapp
```

I get the output "Hello World"

but when i want to run this program in a docker-compose with -d then nothing happens:

```
Starting AA... done
Starting BB ... done
Starting consoleapp ... done
```

Is there a way to see the output?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting console output from Docker container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33083385/getting-console-output-from-docker-container)

Answer (score 1):

Try running compose without `-d`, it will show you the stdout of the containers on the screen, with `-d` it daemonizes the containers -
 `$ docker-compose up`

In case you want to daemonize it, you can use service name defined in docker compose to get the container logs like -
 `$ docker-compose up -d ; docker-compose logs consoleapp`

Ref - https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/logs/